# I/O redirection

Tags: c, windows, redirect, ascii

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   for(i=1; i<=255; i++)
   {
       printf("%d %c\n",i,i);
   }
}
```

Hey i am working my way out from i/o redirection, and i got stuck in outputting ascii table from command prompt i done this.

```
C:\New folder\practice> main.exe > temp.txt

C:\New folder\practice> type temp.txt
```

and after hitting enter (after type `temp.txt`) it only outputs first 26 numbers. My question is why?

Also can someone explain me how to just copy the code into text file using redirection I know how to do using FILE I/O.

Comment: The problem is not your program but the `type` command which stops as soon as it reads the Windows EOF character (ASCII code 26). Open your `text.txt` file with notepad and you'll see that it's fine. `type` acts like this probably for historical reasons.

Comment: And please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you're using MS-DOS... er MS WinDOS, and there ASCII number 26/^Z is the end-of-text-file mark.

The feature exists so that the environment is compatible with the [CP/M operating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M) of the early 1970s, in case you'd need to use some files that originate from that. As you've noticed, only `type` works like that, but `more` would display more... (no pun intended).

No kidding.

Comment: Hey, i just used more in place of type, but this time it did  not stop at 26 :(

Comment: MSVC implements a text mode in its POSIX layer (i.e. `_read`), which generally is the source of Ctrl+Z and CRLF handling of text files. But CMD's `type` command actually implements this on its own.

Comment: Some Windows command-line utilities, such as more.com, do not use the C runtime library's standard I/O. Instead they use a C++ library named ulib.dll, which implements its own stream class hierarchy (e.g. `STREAM` => `BUFFER_STREAM` => `FILE_STREAM`), which wraps the Windows file API. The `FILE_STREAM` class reads files as memory-mapped, with EOF determined strictly by the mapping size. OTOH, ulib's `KEYBOARD` stream (console input) does implement Ctrl+Z. For example, if you run `more.com` with no arguments, it echoes console input, and Ctrl+Z anywhere on a line quits.

Comment: @eryksun time to write an answer :D

Comment: Your answer is correct. I was just providing some context.

Answer (score 2):

It is very dangerous to write non ASCII characters in a *text* stream. `0x10` is `\n` and and can be changed into the underlying system end of line which is `\r\n` on Windows.

The correct way is to open a file in binary mode:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int i;
   FILE *fd = fopen("temp.txt", "wb");
   if (NULL == fd) {
      perror("Error opening file");
      return 1;
   }
   for(i=1; i<=255; i++)
   {
       fprintf(fd, "%d %c\n",i,i);
   }
   fclose(fd);
   return 0;
}
```

That being said, commands expecting text files may stop when they read a *SUB* control character (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> code 0x1A), which is you current problem...